Can Credential Manager display all available sign-in options, including Google accounts, Microsoft accounts, and Autofill account in a login dialog?
During login process, can Credential Manager display a login options dialog that lists all available sign-in options, including Google accounts, Microsoft accounts, as well as accounts stored by Autofill and passkeys? Is there a way to implement this?
I read this instruction here https://developer.android.com/identity/sign-in/credential-manager and I know Credential Manager supports multiple sign-in methods such as passkey, username and password, and autofill. Is there a way to display sign-in options including Google accounts, Microsoft accounts, as well as accounts stored by Autofill and passkeys in one login options dialog? Can Credential Manager get Microsoft accounts? Thanks

It cannot show Microsoft federated credentials, but it can show Google federated credentials, username/passwords and passkeys. On Android 14+, the sources for the last two includes all installed and enabled password managers (including the Google Password Manager) on the device; for versions below 14, it only uses Google Password Manager as the source.
